# How to add keyboard switch buttons below of custom keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I make a custom keyboard with stickers and i show images on keyboard keys to switch the keyboard but we need to show bottom button as a plain strip.Please help me if any one have a idea. I want keyboard like this

[image]

This is my keyboard last row

```
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key
        android:codes="322"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/ai_dark"
        android:keyWidth="16%p" />
   <!-- <Key
        android:codes="327"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/fav"
        android:keyWidth="15%p" />-->

    <Key
        android:codes="324"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/smilee"
        android:keyWidth="17%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="325"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/giff"
        android:keyWidth="17%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="323"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/pic"
        android:keyWidth="17%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="326"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/global"
        android:keyWidth="17%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="67"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/backspace_new"
        android:keyWidth="16%p" />

</Row>
```

Comment: remove the background color or use png images.. also remove padding/margins

Comment: I set these keys in keyboard xml and i have no idea how to show these keys as a image